# Given n points in a 2-D plane we have to find k nearest neighbours of each point among themselves

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, nearest-neighbor

I explored the method using a min-heap. For each point we can store a min heap of size k but it takes too much space for large n(I m targeting for n around a 100 million). Surely there must be a better way of doing this utilising lesser space and not affecting time complexity that much. Is there some other data structure?

Comment: How large value of **n** influences on 'much space' - heap size is **k**? Have you considered https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree for you data set size?

Comment: I think meta is considering one minheap for each point. So there would be total `n` min-heap with size `k`, thus taking `n*k` space in total.

Comment: @SauravSahu Yes, I thought of it like that.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is typical setup for [KD-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Such solution would have linearithmic complexity but may be relatively complex to implement(if a ready implementation is not available)

An alternative approach could be using bucketing to reduce the complexity of the naive algorithm. The idea is to separate the plane into "buckets" i.e. squares of some size and place the points in the bucket they belong to. The closest points will be from the closest buckets. In case of random data this could be quite good improvement but the worst case is still the same as the naive approach.

Comment: I will learn about KD-Tree. Also the bucketing approach seems quite good. What data structure do you think would be appropriate for its implementation? I think a breadth first search on a graph with edges representing adjacency among buckets(nodes) in the 2D plane would be quite good.

Comment: For the implementation I imagine, you could use either a 2d matrix with a cell for each bucket or a hashtable(or some other associative array) if you expect most buckets to be empty